# Vector is not incrementable error

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I am writing a program in C++ implementing the Newton-Raphson method, among other things, and I have defined a polynomial class:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <utility>
#include <string>
#include <cmath>
#include <vector>
#include <set>

using namespace std;

class polynomial{

    using pair_dd = pair<double, double>;

public:
    polynomial(const vector<pair_dd>& v) : m_coeff(simplify(v)) {} // constructor
    polynomial(const polynomial& p) : m_coeff(p.m_coeff){} // copy constructor
    polynomial derivative() const{ // computes derivative
        vector<pair_dd> dcoeff;
        for_each(begin(m_coeff), end(m_coeff), [&](pair_dd p){
            dcoeff.emplace_back(pair_dd(p.first*p.second, p.second - 1));
        });
        return polynomial(dcoeff);
    }
    double apply(double x) const{ // applies poly to argument
        auto sum(0.0);
        for_each(begin(m_coeff), end(m_coeff), [&](pair_dd p){
            sum += p.first*pow(x, p.second);
        });
        return sum;
    }
    void write() const{ // prints polynomial
        // function just for testing
        for (const auto& term : m_coeff)
            cout << term.first << "x^" << term.second << " +";
        cout << endl;
    }

private:
    polynomial(); //forbid empty constructor
    vector<pair_dd> m_coeff;
    vector<pair_dd> simplify(const vector<pair_dd>& v) const{

        set<double> exp; // set of exponents
        for (const auto& term : v)
            exp.insert(term.second);

        vector<pair_dd> ret; // final simplified vector
        vector<pair_dd> temp; // temporary object

        for (const auto& power : exp){
            copy_if(begin(v), end(v), begin(temp), [&](const pair_dd p){
                return (p.second == power);
            });
            // combine terms
            auto sum(0.0);
            for (auto& p : temp)
                sum += p.first;
            ret.push_back(pair_dd(sum, power));
            temp.clear();
        }
        return ret;
    }
};


int main(){

    vector<pair<double, double>> vec;
    vec.push_back(pair<double, double>(5,1)); // 5x
    vec.push_back(pair<double, double>(10, 1)); // 10x
    vec.push_back(pair<double, double>(3, 2)); // 3x^2

    polynomial poly(vec);

    // should write 15x + 3x^2

    poly.write();
    return 0;
}
```

The problem I am having is with the `simplify` function which is giving rise to an error during runtime at the location of `copy_if`. It is said that the

> vector temp is not incrementable

in Visual Studio. The way my algorithm works is by gathering all terms with the same power of x, in a set (since we want only unique elements). Subsequently, I iterate through the exponent set, using the `copy_if` on the vector of pairs to group together all terms with the same exponent, which are then combined and put into the final vector.

I have tried both reserving and resizing the temporary vector.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`copy_if` will not allocate memory , it assumes that `temp` is already sized, which it isn't. You can use [`std::back_inserter`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/back_inserter) out of `<iterator>`.

```
copy_if(begin(v), end(v), back_inserter(temp), [&](const pair_dd p){
    return (p.second == power);
});
```

Comment: Thank you for your prompt response - your solution works perfectly, and the program executes without any other errors... a first for me! :)

Answer (score 3):

You're trying to copy into an empty vector, you need to resize it first, or use an inserter that will resize as needed:

```
copy_if(begin(v), end(v), back_inserter(temp), [&](const pair_dd p){
            return (p.second == power);
        });
```